# File 'blockfrost-mainnet.key' specified in the --blockfrost-token-file can't be read

Tags: cardano-cli, wallet

I am running this command to run the Cardano light node using cardano-wallet cli

`docker pull inputoutput/cardano-wallet:2022.4.27 serve --light --mainnet --blockfrost-token-file blockfrost-mainnet.key`

The file blockfrost-mainnet.key contains the blockfrost project API key, when I execute the command I got the following error:

````
[cardano-wallet.main:Debug:4] [2022-04-28 14:20:55.15 UTC] ServeArgs {_hostPreference = Host "127.0.0.1", _mode = Light "blockfrost-mainnet.key", _listen = ListenOnPort 8090, _tlsConfig = Nothing, _networkConfiguration = MainnetConfig, _database = Nothing, _syncTolerance = SyncTolerance 300s, _enableShutdownHandler = False, _poolMetadataSourceOpt = Nothing, _tokenMetadataSourceOpt = Nothing, _logging = LoggingOptions {loggingMinSeverity = Debug, loggingTracers = Tracers {applicationTracer = Const (Just Info), apiServerTracer = Const (Just Info), tokenMetadataTracer = Const (Just Info), walletEngineTracer = Const (Just Info), walletDbTracer = Const (Just Info), poolsEngineTracer = Const (Just Info), poolsDbTracer = Const (Just Info), ntpClientTracer = Const (Just Info), networkTracer = Const (Just Info)}, loggingTracersDoc = Nothing}}
[cardano-wallet.main:Error:4] [2022-04-28 14:20:55.15 UTC] File 'blockfrost-mainnet.key' specified in the --blockfrost-token-file can't be read.
[cardano-wallet.main:Debug:4] [2022-04-28 14:20:55.15 UTC] Logging shutdown.```
````

Comment: Are the read permissions for the blockfrost-mainnet.key set appropriately?

Comment: i found the way i am not sure how its possible but using cardano-wallet binaries or installation works for me instead of using docker image.

Answer (score 0):

Your probably did not mount your `blockfrost-mainnet.key` and therefore it is not accessible within the Docker container.

Check [the docker documentation](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/) about bind mounts.